# Secure FTP Files for Download by iOS Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ftp

I want the user to be able to download a .txt/.mp3/.jpg from an FTP to the device (currently working) - however this is not at all secure. Is there a way i can secure this by adding a username and password on those files or something similar?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to download files, why not try http download and https for secure? And you can post the username/password to http/https server, depend it you can identify users and set their permissions.

If you are sure of that you do really need ftp, try ftp over ssh.

http://www.simonblog.com/2009/05/17/how-to-use-ssh-to-transfer-file-on-iphone/